# Jmeter in Cloud Setup with 30k User Load

Tags: performance, jmeter, remote-server, distributed-testing

I want to test a mobile application with 30k load in jmeter with cloud set-up,as i have never done such a huge v.user load in jmeter and with distributed load,please help me how to proceed with detailed step by step.

I have worked in jmter for past 5-6 months but with only one load generator machine with 200-300 V.user.

Answer (score 2):

The approach is the same but with one interim step.

1. Configure JMeter for the maximum performance. See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) for tuning tips.
2. Determine how many users you are able to simulate from a single machine (gradually increase the number of users and monitor load generator resources consumption)
3. Calculate how many machines you will need
4. Install JMeter and run jmeter-server on them. See [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html) guide for details
5. Run your test, analyze results, raise issues.

Answer (score 1):

The JMeter [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) brilliantly captures how to run a distributed test. With that said, in a nutshell -

1. you would need one machine to act as a master and others as a slave
2. manage your data on each node (look at setting up some CI tool to help run some copy jobs before you kick off your test. This will help copy your test data accordingly)

Answer (score -1):

You have 3 options:

- Simple One : Use a SAAS solution that offers JMeter, there a many:

  - [Redline13](https://www.redline13.com/blog/)
  - Flood.io
  - Blazemeter
  - LoadFocus
- Use this free [tool](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2) that allows load testing on AWS
- Use JMeter distributed testing, you can see this [new tutorial](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html) from Apache JMeter

To ensure you have the most efficient test, ensure you follow [best-practices](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/).